# Move free space from end of the drive to first partition with gparted

Tags: partition, disk, gparted

I am in a frustrating situation - no matter how I try, gparted won't let me assign the empty space to the first partition:

[image: image description]

The middle partition is blocking me from expanding `/dev/sda1`. I need to move partition `/dev/sda2` to the end of the drive, like so (fabricated image):

[image: image description]

Then I will be able to expand first partition:

[image: image description]

How to do that? I assume data from `/dev/sda2` must be physically copied to end of the drive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is recommended that, before making any changes, you make backups of any data you do not want to lose in case anything goes wrong.

Before you start, both partitions will need to be unmounted– if you cannot unmount one of them (e.g. because it is your root partition), use a live CD with GParted (e.g. the [GParted live CD](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) or the Ubuntu live CD) and resize them that way.

Select the second (extended) partition, and click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Use the right handle to extend the partition to the end of the free space, and then click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Select the contained swap partition, and click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Drag the partition to the end of the extended partition, and then click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
You can safely click OK on this warning message, as we are only moving a swap partition.
[image: Warning message: "Moving a partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot[. ...] Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows system partition C:. [...]"]
Select the extended partition again and click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Use the left handle to shrink the partition to the end of the free space, and then click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Then, select the first partition, and click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Use the right handle to extend the partition to the end of the free space, and then click on *Resize/Move*.
[image]
Finally, click on *Apply* and your partitions should be reformatted.
[image]

Comment: +1. also, http://gparted.org/ has a downloadable CD / USB image that can be used.

Comment: Good point - might be more suited for this job

Comment: How to do the same with text mode parted or any other console tool ?

Comment: Thanks for the great tutorial!  I don't think I would have been able to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Note that you might need to "deactivate" a partition (i.e. take it offline) to move it.